# Issue with Cookie Security: Overlay Broad Path

Tags: java, spring, cookies, jakarta-ee, cookie-path

I've two applications with a common domain name i.e let's say **www.kishore.com/travelSite** and **www.kishore.com/researchSite**.
So, in the *travelSite* I'm creating a cookie as below

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("someName","someValue");
cookie.setSecure(true);
cookie.setHttpOnly(true);
cookie.setPath("/");
```

Here the reason I'm setting Path to / in **travelSite** is because, I want this cookie to be used in **researchSite**. But the problem is, when I send this code for scanning, it says it's vulnerable to use context path i.e /.
 Setting this **/travelSite** could eliminate vulnerable error in scanning but can't be used the the **researchSite**.
Wanted to know if there is a workaround? Can I set domain name i.e kishore.com in the cookie path. If so how?

Comment: What do you think `setDomain` on the `Cookie` does?

Comment: @M.Deinum It sets the domain name i.e setDomain("Kishore.com") ? If I'm not wrong.
But still when we set setPath("/") it'll be like Kishore.com/ only right. which is the root context?

Comment: Correct (and which should be mainly the same as now). So you either specify multiple cookies or ignore the warning. Or find a different way instead of a cookie (like a header).